# Scaffold-DbContext multiple Schemas with specific tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a single database that has multiple schema's. The two schemas are Bob and Bill.
Both Bob and Bill contain Table1 Table2 and Table3. When I call Scaffold-DbContext it to just generate scaffold for Table1, Table2, Table3 for a single schema "Bob" which is what I thought I would run this command.

```
Scaffold-DbContext -t Table1 Table2 Table3 -schema "Bob"
```

When I run that command I get all tables in the database including Table1, Table2, Table3 from Both Schema's why is this and what can I do to just get a single schema and Table1, Table2, Table3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only -t option with schema.tablename syntax

Comment: Thank-you so much! This is a life saver!

Comment: for multiple schemas, and specific tables, how would i go about it? right now, i am trying this but it get ALL the tables from the mentioned schemas. `Scaffold-DbContext "My-postgresql-connectionstring" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o DbModels  -UseDatabaseNames -Force -Context "PgDbContext" -Schema "schema1", "schema2" -t schema1.table1, schema1.table2, schema2.table11, schema2.table22`. What am i doing wrong and where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, multiple table names should also be comma separated:

`Scaffold-DbContext -t Bob.Table1, Bob.Table2, Bob.Table3`

If any table name contains spaces (somethings out of our control), quote the table name as well:

`Scaffold-DbContext -t "Bob.Table 1", "Bob.Table 2", "Bob.Table 3"`